# compiler complains on casting to same capture group

Tags: java, generics

The following throws a compile error because foo.getClass() isn't the same capture group as F extends Foo somehow:

```
public <F extends Foo> F create (final F foo){

     return foo.getClass().cast(foo);

   }
```

The following works fine.

```
return foo;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object#getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29), not a `Class<F extends Foo>`.

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

The erasure of `<F extends Foo>` is the upper bound, `Foo`. Therefore the `Class#cast()` call is roughly equivalent to

```
return (Foo) foo;
```

and not

```
return (F) foo;
```

As you've probably figured out by now, a `Foo` is not an `F extends Foo` (the declared method return type), so the compiler won't let you return a `Foo`.